# request.path in django template

Tags: django

I try something like this:

```
{% if request.path == 'contact' %}
    <p>You are in Contact</p>
{% endif %}

{% if request.path == 'shop' %}
    <p>You are in Shop</p>
{% endif %}
```

Why does not that work?

Comment: What is in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting?

Comment: @Brandon I don't have this conf in my settings.py. I use django 1.4.5. I think I have the default settings.

Comment: Try to output `{{ request.path }}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default Django's template processors are

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

( see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) )

You need `django.core.context_processors.request` to use `request` in templates, so add it to that list in **settings.py**. If you don't have that variable there then set it.

Comment: from Django 1.10+ use 'django.template.context_processors.request'

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
{% if 'contact' in request.path %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
{% if request.path == '/contact/' %}
    <p>You are in Contact</p>
{% elif request.path == '/shop/' %}
    <p>You are in Shop</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: request.path gives you the entire path so it would be /something/someting/contact/ if the path looks like that. that is.

Comment: Exactly. You have to check for the entire path, I just based my example on what was provided :)

Comment: Try to check `{% if 'contact/' in reuqest.path %}`. So you do not need to check the full path.

Answer (score 0):

**before 1.8**
**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'other.required.processors.names',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

**views.py (using className.as_view)**

```
from django.template import *

class className(TemplateView):
    template_name = "name.html"
```

**views.py (normal use)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def name(request):
    return render_to_response('name.html'{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```