# Get Request in all views

Tags: django

How do I make sure '**request**' in always in my template? For example if I want to call the following in a template:

```
request.get_full_path
```

I always have to include it in my context (within the view) like this....

```
context = {'form': form,'request':request}
return render_to_response('contacts/group.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this for all my view at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just answered similar question here: [request.path in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436407/request-path-in-django-template/15436846#15436846) (can't mark it as duplicate as the answer is not accepted yet).

Basically you need to define TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable in your **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    // DEFAULT
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    // for request
    "django.core.context_processors.request"
)
```

Now `request` will be available in all templates.