# How can I compare request.path and user.username in a template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have tried with

```
{% if request.path == "/{{user.username}}" %}
                  You are in Contact</p>
  {% else %}
            nono
```

But It doesn't work

Comment: HTML does not have a template engine. Are you using one from a language in particular?

Comment: I'm using that in Django

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436407/request-path-in-django-template

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template

Comment: Nothing of that works

Comment: `doesn't work` what does this mean? Error? Wrong behavior? `You are in Contact` in contact with himself? What is `user` here, which path are you comparing it to?

Comment: I agree is user.username and request.path really the same here? What do you want to reach? The path seems to return a full path as string whereas the user only contains a max 150 characters username. Please share some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it fails, output something useful so you can see why:

```
{% if request.path == "/{{ user.username }}" %}
    You are in Contact
{% else %}
    {{ request.path }} is not the same as /{{ user.username }}
{% endif %}
```